# How to print word and excel document using java application?

Tags: java, excel, ms-word

How to print word and excel file in java ? when i am trying to print that word or excel file i am getting encoded content as a print.
Is there any solution available using i can print my doc file using java program?

Please find the code below

```
XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(new File("D://TEST.docx")));
         XWPFWordExtractor we = new XWPFWordExtractor(docx);

        try {
                new RemotePrintService().print(we.getText().getBytes(), "Default-Printer","");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: which library are you using ?

Comment: can you post your code please.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Desktop desktop=Desktop.getDesktop();
if (desktop.isSupported(Desktop.Action.PRINT))
    desktop.print(new File("yourFile.docx"));
```

Comment: Assuming the applications are installed

Comment: I want to print that doc file using java application silently.

Comment: silently means? @PramodMall